# Dungeon petz 2 or 3 player game: how many cages should be replenished?

Tags: dungeon-petz

The rules has a separate passage for replenishing cages:

> If one of the two cage-buying action spaces is
>   blocked by a neutral imp, you deal only 1 new cage, leaving one pit empty. Apparently, the neutral imp took one cage before you could get there.

- This rule seems to assume that the board starts with one cage and 2 open slots every round: replenish one, leave one open.
- What if the board starts with any other number of cages? We had rounds starting with both 3 and 2 cages. In these cages we would possibly not replenish? Or even remove a cage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two sentences of that section still apply, and state

> At least one cage will be left over from the previous round. Take the
>   lowest of the leftover cages, put it in the uppermost pit and discard
>   the rest.

It isn't possible for all 3 cages to be purchased in a turn, so at least one will always be there.  Keep the lowest, move it to the upper slot, and get rid of the rest.  That way you are guaranteed to always have a single slot filled.  Then you either deal 2 more, or only 1 more if a neutral imp is blocking a space.